# How to make canvas invisible to eye but not to mousemove event?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouseevent

I have some colored lines in a canvas which I scan using a `mousemove` event, which returns the line's hex color code.
Is there anyway I could make this canvas invisible to the eye, but when the pointer goes over the canvas, still returns the correct color code?

I've tried setting the context's `globalAlpha` to transparent or near transparent (0, 0.1...) with mixed results in the [following fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sc28/7w45xu3e/):

- In Firefox, the collected hex returns an altered color due to transparency,
- In Chrome, it returns the correct color regardless of transparency (this is actually the behavior I want).

And oddly, in my original code, even in Chrome, canvas lines with `globalAlpha=0` no longer return their original color.

Can someone kindly explain what the expected behavior for globalAlpha is? More importantly, is there another way to make a canvas invisible to the eye but which still allows collecting the colors with a mouse event? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set CSS property `opacity` to `0`.

When you apply the property to your canvas like

```
#examplecanvas {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

It will vanish from the screen but still detect color when you mouse over it (or click it).

Comment: this is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot! I encountered some conflicts setting the CSS opacity to the canvas class in my code (maybe overridden by the parent or something?), but using the ID as you suggest worked fine. thanks again :)